# Place tabs inside a tabhost in android

Tags: android

I have an application in which i have 5 tabs which is at the bottom.
Now inside the first tab I need 4 tabs that is aligned at the top.
How can I do that? PLease help.
I only managed to create the first 5 tabs and when I tried to place an activity inside the first one the app crashes.
I am extending the TabActivity for the first 5 tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity that is started by the first tab can also extend TabActivity, so you just need to add a TabHost to your Tab1Activity's layout.